# Delphi - Registry Startup

Tags: delphi

How to make my program edit the registry so it can start on the computer startup?
using

```
TRegistry
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the following location in the registry:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

You can use TRegistry to add entries here.

Comment: Thank you . If I could I would have +1 you :D

Comment: To avoid the next post, it is better to use HKCU instead.

Comment: It depends if you want it to run for one (HKCU) or all (HKLM)

Comment: From what I understand HKLM will make all of the users on this computer to start this program up while HKCU will make only the current active user to start it up

Comment: What @user539484 means is that you program will typically not have write access to HKLM. So you will either need to gain write access to HKLM, or write under the HKCU registry key. In that case though, your program will only start upon logon for the user that was logged on when the reg key was written. The bottom line with all of this is that such a change is best done when your install program runs because that's when you can reasonably expect to have write access to HKLM.

Comment: Ok and I have another question , Is there a variable which contain a string of the corrent program location? for example "d:/"

Comment: Found it - application.exename if anyone need :]

Comment: @Chriseyre2000, none of those for my taste :-) I'm coming to that conclusion every time i'm cleaning up Run keys :-)

Comment: It seems like when im creating another variable of TRegistry It doesnt have any access to the registry Unless I do free to the first variable of type Tregistry

Comment: @HTxL if you edited your question (or start a new one) to include your code and problems in some detail, you're more likely to get well-focused answers.

Answer (score 2):

hey try this code to start your application on the next startup

```
    procedure RunOnStartupHKCU(const sCmdLine: string;) ;
       var
       sKey              : string;
       Section           : string;
       ApplicationTitle  : string;
       begin
        ApplicationTitle:='myApplication';
        sKey := 'Once'
        Section := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run' + sKey + #0;

       with TRegIniFile.Create('') do
         try
           RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
           WriteString(Section, ApplicationTitle, sCmdLine) ;
         finally
         Free;
        end;
       end;
```

To call the it use this

```
     sAppNam:=Application.ExeName;
     RunOnStartupHKCU(sAppNam) ;
```